# How ensure external HTML is loaded before running script

Tags: jquery, settimeout

Two days of searching through all related posts and no success.
My code uses local-storage to store and retrieve the status of checkboxes when the page is refreshed.  This works well.  I've since extended my code to load the checkboxes into a div from an external HTML file and this is causing timing problems.  The code to manage local-storage is being run too quickly for the checkboxes to be loaded into the div.   Numerous efforts at delaying the code have failed, my latest effort being 'setTimeout', which doesn't have the intended effect (see fiddle).  Incidentally, with enough 'alerts' stopping the code I've proved that all this can work.  Please help me with the best way forward.  Much appreciated.  https://jsfiddle.net/Ldn2awxb/

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js


<div id="CountryCheckboxContainer">

<!--      Checkboxes below are loaded from external HTML file   

   <label><input type="checkbox"  id="UN8" value="Albania" />Albania</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox"  id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox"  id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
-->
</div>




// Load from external files
function LoadCheckboxes() {
setTimeout(function()
  { $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").load( "https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0");
  }, 500);
}


// set and get items
$(function() {

LoadCheckboxes();

  var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#CountryCheckboxContainer :checkbox");

  $checkboxes.on("change", function() {
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
  });

  // On page load
  $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) provides the option to supply a callback function that's called on successful completion. Rather than using `.load()` as part of your setup, do setup as part of `.load()`:

```
$(function(){
  function setupCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#CountryCheckboxContainer :checkbox");

    $checkboxes.on("change", function() {
      $checkboxes.each(function() {
        checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
      });
      localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
    });

    $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });
  };

  $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").load( "https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0", setupCheckboxes);
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know .load() had a callback.  Nevertheless I'm struggling to get this to work for me... perhaps I'm not understanding where exactly to place the code.

Comment: @Silverburch I have realized I misinterpreted some of your code. I've updated my answer based on my new understanding.

Comment: no problem.. I was pulling my hair out there for a bit!    Thing is I still can't get this to work... tried in Firefox and IE (all latest).  Does it work for you?

Comment: @Silverburch That url provides a complete page rather than an html fragment. Injecting it into a page isn't going to provide the results you anticipate. If it is actually supposed to be used in a page, it's probably intended to be placed in an `iframe` rather than loaded via Javascript.

Comment: @Silverburch Additionally, the page supplied by that url appears to be malformed. While browsers will fix it up, jQuery has issues with it. Otherwise, it does appear to load and the callback is being called. https://jsfiddle.net/h9L4fayx/

Comment: I understand very well your explanations.  So I added the id of the specific div to the end of the URL:  "https://c2ec... #ExternalHTMLCountryStorage"   and now your code works beautifully.  You're a star!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is load your content and then call the bindings. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0',
  success: function(content){
     $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").html(content);
     //Put your behaviors here.
  }
})
```

You also can do it by this way synchronously executing your code. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0',
  async: false, //It makes stops JS execution in the page,
  success: function(content){
    $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").html(content);
  }
})
//And just keep your normal code.
```

If you have another important JS content being executed, such as Google analytics or bootstrap, it's gonna be a problem and really much better doing the first option.

Comment: You should not set `async` to `false`. It is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions of jQuery.